# Django queryset field lookup list of objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to create a query of field lookup (part of a longer query).
The field is a JsonField that contains a list of objects with attributes "id" and "type".
This is the model (partial):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    my_list = JSONField(default=dict)
```

Let's say I have this value in my_list:

```
my_model.my_list = [{"id": "12345", "type": "2"},
                    {"id": "23456", "type": "3"}
                   ]
```

and I want to check if any of the 'id's contains any of list of 'id's

for example:

```
ids = ['12345', '45678']
```

I can do something like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(my_list__contains=[{'id': '12345'}]) | Q(my_list__contains=[{'id':'45678'}]))
```

In that case, I will need to take that list of ids and somehow create this query out of it.
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Won't `MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=['12345', '45678'])` work for you?

Comment: @Rfroes87 no - 'id' in this case is an attribute inside the object. But I understand the confusion, I will change the names.

Comment: I think maybe @Rfroes87 meant something like: MyModel.objects.filter(my_list__id__in=ids)

Comment: @getup8 tried that as well. It didn't work.

Comment: @user2880391 what error do you get? Yeah I'm not sure `in` is available for JSON fields. You might consider writing a raw query instead? And if you can't figure out a way to do it, maybe log a feature request with Django. I'll dig around a bit more too..

Comment: Create your own custom query managers.